# Makefile defining folder structure to find program and includes

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my folder structure:

- root/Makefile
- root/src/main.cpp
- root/include

This is my Makefile:

```
# Define compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# Build target executable
DIR = src
TARGET = main
INCLUDES = include

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

I'm confused about how I add my $DIR variable to my target, do I need to do it on every instance of $TARGET and is it just formatted like this:

```
$(DIR)/$(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following change make help you to compile successfully. You need to first move into DIR folder. so, used cd $(DIR).

```
# Define compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# Build target executable
DIR = src
TARGET = main
INCLUDES = ../include

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
    cd $(DIR) &
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    cd $(DIR) &
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean it's now looking for includes in ~/src/include instead of ~/include though?

Comment: Yes, you need to set INCLUDES = ../include with this.